# wildcard match & replace and/or multiple string wildcard matching

Tags: python, regex, wildcard

I have two very related questions:

- I want to match a string pattern with a wildcard (i.e. containing one or more '*' or '?')
  and then form a replacement string with a second wildcard pattern. There the placeholders should refer to the *same* matched substring
  (As for instance in the DOS copy command)

  Example: `pattern='*.txt'` and `replacement-pattern='*.doc'`:
  I want `aaa.txt` --> `aaa.doc` and `xx.txt.txt` --> `xx.txt.doc`

  Ideally it would work with multiple, arbitrarily placed wildcards: e.g., `pattern='*.*'` and `replacement-pattern='XX*.*'`.

  Of course one needs to apply some constraints (e.g. greedy strategy). Otherwise patterns such as `X*X*X` are not unique for string `XXXXXX`.
- or, alternatively, form a multi-match. That is I have one or more wildcard patterns each with the same number of wildcard characters. Each pattern is matched to one string but the wildcard characters should refer to the same matching text.

  Example: `pattern1='*.txt'` and `pattern2='*-suffix.txt`
  Should match the pair `string1='XX.txt'` and `string2='XX-suffix.txt'` but not
  `string1='XX.txt'` and `string2='YY-suffix.txt'`

  In contrast to the first this is a more well defined problem as it avoids the ambiguity problem but is perhaps quite similar.

I am sure there are algorithms for these tasks, however, I am unable to find anything useful.

The Python library has `fnmatch` but this is does not support what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but I came up with the following, which should work for your first question. Based on your examples I’m assuming you don’t want to match whitespace.

This function turns the first passed pattern into a regex and the passed replacement pattern into a string suitable for the `re.sub` function.

```
import re

def replaceWildcards(string, pattern, replacementPattern):
    splitPattern = re.split(r'([*?])', pattern)
    splitReplacement = re.split(r'([*?])', replacementPattern)
    if (len(splitPattern) != len(splitReplacement)):
        raise ValueError("Provided pattern wildcards do not match")
    reg = ""
    sub = ""
    for idx, (regexPiece, replacementPiece) in enumerate(zip(splitPattern, splitReplacement)):
        if regexPiece in ["*", "?"]:
            if replacementPiece != regexPiece:
                raise ValueError("Provided pattern wildcards do not match")
            reg += f"(\\S{regexPiece if regexPiece == '*' else ''})" # Match anything but whitespace
            sub += f"\\{idx + 1}" # Regex matches start at 1, not 0
        else:
            reg += f"({re.escape(regexPiece)})"
            sub += f"{replacementPiece}"
    return re.sub(reg, sub, string)
```

Sample output:

```
replaceWildcards("aaa.txt xx.txt.txt aaa.bat", "*.txt", "*.doc")
# 'aaa.doc xx.txt.doc aaa.bat'

replaceWildcards("aaa10.txt a1.txt aaa23.bat", "a??.txt", "b??.doc")
# 'aab10.doc a1.txt aaa23.bat'

replaceWildcards("aaa10.txt a1-suffix.txt aaa23.bat", "a*-suffix.txt", "b*-suffix.doc")
# 'aaa10.txt b1-suffix.doc aaa23.bat'

replaceWildcards("prefix-2aaa10-suffix.txt a1-suffix.txt", "prefix-*a*-suffix.txt", "prefix-*b*-suffix.doc")
# 'prefix-2aab10-suffix.doc a1-suffix.txt
```

Note f-strings require Python >=3.6.

Comment: Great. Good idea to build a regex and use `re.sub`. I did a bit of fine-tuning (use . instead of \S to match also whitespace, match full string only with ^ and $ and slash-escape the replacementPiece `sub` part) and it works really well.